# How to catch the "Login Failed" event?

Tags: users

I want to show a custom block, only when log in has failed.
So from visibility settings I have to put a PHP code that returns TRUE only when the login has failed.

But how could I "catch" that event? Do I have to use variable_get(..)? And if yes, how could I use that?with what attributes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rules module for this if you don't want to write PHP.

If you want it to be an ajax event you will need to write a custom login form.

The user.module has a set of functions you can call for validation: [`user_login_final_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7).

I suggest rules module, save yourself some time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried rules module, but in the dropwdown list with the events it doesn't have "log in failed". It has only events for User loged in, user loged out and some others.  So that means that rules module can't do that, or I have to search it more? (I am asking you since you know how to use it)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [`user_login_final_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7). Using this validate function you could set a variable that you then can check with php to show your custom block.

I guess you will have to add your own validation routine for the login form.

This link may point you in the right direction: [Adding Secondary Validation to Drupal’s User Login](http://www.automation-excellence.com/blog/adding-secondary-validation-drupal%E2%80%99s-user-login).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [user_login_default_validators()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_default_validators/7). You can add your own function to the series of validation functions. If you add your function at the end of the list you can check the values and do whatever processing your block requires.